# How do you determine the function representing the surjective map say for example $f: C\to S$ where $S=\left\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^2+y^2=r^2\right\}\,?$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> How do you determine the function representing the surjective map say for example $f: C\to S$ where $S=\left\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=r^2\right\}\;?$

$C$ in this question stands for the cylinder.

Hi everyone! I am really confused with how to know which $f(x)$ should I have so that I can map $C$ into $S$. I don’t have a single idea on how this works at all. I have seen a few examples but I always end up not getting anything from it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There will be more than $f$ though one is particularly easy to specify if you know how  points on the cylinder $C$ are described. You then want to show you have $f:C\to S$ and each point $s \in S$ has at least one $c \in C$ with $f(c)=s$

Comment: You should also give a precise definition of $C$. And what does "the function representing the surjective map"  mean? Do you want to a find *some* surjection $f : C \to S$? There are many ...